# CPU/memory monitor using wxpython matplotlib and funcanimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have designed `cpu/memory` monitor using `wxpython matplotlib` and `funcanimation`.

Problem description:

```
self.line_animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.update_lines, frames = 25, interval = 1000, blit = False)
```

This is how I am starting the animation.

[image]

Everything works fine till I reach `frame 25`, after that at least from the plotted graph I see a reset kind of behavior. 
This is happening after every `cycle of 25 frames`.

```
def update_lines(self, num):
        self.get_system_info()
        for counter, value in self.data.iteritems():
            self.graph_lines[counter].set_data(self.times, value[1])
        self.cpu_axes.relim()  # Recalculate limits
        self.cpu_axes.autoscale_view(True, True, True)
        self.cpu_axes.legend()
        self.mem_axes.relim()  # Recalculate limits
        self.mem_axes.autoscale_view(True, True, True)
        self.system_canvas.draw()
```

Question: what could be the issue?

Comment: hi guys, i am new to stackoverflow , no idea how to attach image....

Comment: probably as beginner you can attache image - you may need more points. Add normal link to image on http://imgur.com

Comment: it normal - animation (as default) runs in loop. `FuncAnimation` has some option to play animation only once. You set `frames=25` so animation create only 25 frames and starts from beginning

Comment: @furas here is a link to image, http://imgur.com/a/YYvSY
can't we have a smooth animation?

Comment: images and all bigger information add to question - it will be more readable.

Comment: better show `update_lines` function - there can be problem

Comment: you should have function `edit` belowe you question - use it to put code.

Comment: I can't run this code so you have to try to use `print()` to check values in variables. check what values you have in self.data, if there is strange value then you have to go to place where you create self.data and check variables. Or maybe this is normal behavior, maybe system uses more CPU when FuncAnimation starts again loop. Maybe you will have to use some `wx` function (some `timer`) to execute function periodically.

Comment: yes that is possible, I think data is consistent. but FuncAnimation may be doing something after each loop.
sample 1 -  'cpu-idle':  [79.6, 86.9, 93.0, 93.4, 92.0, 91.4, 92.0, 92.5, 91.0, 92.0, 91.9, 93.9, 92.5, 92.5, 93.0, 93.5, 92.9, 92.5, 93.0, 92.0]
sample 2 - 'cpu-idle':  [50.0, 93.0, 93.4, 92.5, 86.8, 81.4, 83.6, 92.9, 92.0, 92.4, 92.0, 91.5, 92.5, 93.9, 92.5, 93.5, 92.5, 93.6, 93.9, 92.0]

Comment: maybe use [wx.Timer](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/) instead of `FuncAnimation`

Comment: @furas sure I will try that out. and thanks for guiding me posting material.

Comment: @furas wx.Timer worked like a charm. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

This post is to complete the thread. I solved my issue using wx.Timer as suggested by @furas .

I spent entire day investigating workaround for my issue in FuncAnnimation but no luck!